# How to build a parent with child factory in one step in order to pass validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

Projects must have at least one task created at the same time to ensure the validation passes.  This is the snippet I use to validate this:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :tasks, :length => { :minimum => 1 }
  ...
end
```

The challenge I'm having is create the right factory to build a project with task upfront using FactoryGirl.  I'm using:

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :task do
    name "Get this test passing"
    project
  end

  factory :project do
    title "Complete the application"
    factory :project_with_tasks do
      ignore do
        tasks_count 5
      end

      after(:create) do |project, evaluator|
        FactoryGirl.create_list(:task, evaluator.tasks_count, project: project)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Now the problem is this fails as it actually creates the project, then tries to create the associated task.  The error is reported as:

```
Failure/Error: project = FactoryGirl.create(:project_with_tasks, tasks_count: 2)
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Projects must have at least one task
```

Turning it into `before(:create)` means the project isn't available to reference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up getting it passing by building the factory in the following way:

```
project = FactoryGirl.build(:project)  
project.tasks << FactoryGirl.create(:task)  
project.save
```

This adds the task to the project before a save is done.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try on before(:create) to "build" a task for the project and after(:create) saving them in order to by pass the validation error?

ex:

```
  before(:build) do |instance|
    instance.tasks << build(:task, project: instance)
  end
  after(:create) do |instance|
    instance.tasks.each{|t| t.save!}
  end
```

Comment: I can't find somewhere in rdocs that length applies to associations. Maybe you should define a custom validation method.