# Create Parent and Child with child presence validation Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, testing, factory-bot

Have a project that has Invoices with many Trips. New story came my way requesting that an Invoice MUST have a trip. I've added a validation `validates :trips, presence: true` but it is now blowing up a number of my tests since FactoryGirl is trying to save the invoice before creating the associated trip.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :invoice do
    sequence(:invoice_id) { SecureRandom.uuid}
    merchant
    amount 100.00
    item_count 1
    paid false
    currency "GBP"
    invoice_type "pre-flight"
    service_rendered false
    cancelled false

    after(:create) { |object| create(:trip, invoice_id: object.invoice_id)}
  end

end
```

What can I do to create these objects. Preferably at the factory level since there are numerous tests utilizing this behavior (and currently failing because of it.) [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16235222/how-to-build-a-parent-with-child-factory-in-one-step-in-order-to-pass-validation/16240709#16235222) seems like a good solution at the test level.

**Update**
Still struggling with getting my tests green now. 42 Tests are erroring out with the following code.

> Validation failed: Trips can't be blank

My current updated line in my FactoryGirl code

```
  before(:create) { |object| object << build(:trip, invoice_id: object.invoice_id)}
```

Here is my trip factory as well.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :trip do
    depart_airport "MCI"
    arrive_airport "ORD"
    passenger_first_name "Joe"
    passenger_last_name "Business"
    passenger_count 1
    departure_date {10.days.from_now}
    invoice
  end

end
```

**Working Now**
@andrykonchin was right. I had missed something in my `before(:create)...`

`before(:create) { |object| object.trips << build(:trip, invoice_id: object.invoice_id)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`before` callback may help you.

From the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Callbacks):

> before(:create) - called before a factory is saved (via
>   FactoryGirl.create)

It would look like this:

```
before(:create) { |object| object.details << build(:invoice_detail)}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to create a child with the parent id BEFORE the parent is created?

Comment: @CheeseFry, you can, but foreign key constraints in a database will prevent it. You should not *create*, you have only to *build* a child model and to add it to the (parent model) association; when you save parent model (invoice), new child model will be saved too, like in my example, right?

Comment: Updated my code above that made it worked. Thank you for your example!