# Factory Girl in MiniTest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, factory-bot, minitest

I am piggybacking on my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36848015/create-parent-and-child-with-child-presence-validation-factory-girl) where I have a factory creating a parent and child. I am running my unit tests and have a simple one not passing.

```
test "invoice can save" do
  invoice = build(:invoice)
  assert invoice.save, "Error message: #{invoice.errors.full_messages}"
end
```

Returns the following error.

> Error message: ["Trips can't be blank"]

But the following code works.

```
test "invoice can save" do
  invoice = create(:invoice)
  assert invoice.save, "Error message: #{invoice.errors.full_messages}"
end
```

My understanding is that `build` should be holding it in memory until save is called. Isn't the first a better test to see if it is successfully saving to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the `Factory` in your earlier question, you are calling `before_create` to set the `trip`. However, you are not creating the object, you're `build`ing it.

If you changed that `before_create` to an `after_build` it *should* resolve that persnickety test!

Here's a helpful link to an [old article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/aint-no-calla-back-girl) from Thoughtbots about the "callbacks" available in FactoryGirl

Comment: 1st Thank you for using the adjective persnickety.  
2nd Thank you for digging through this and the linked question with me. 
I'll be sure to give that article you linked a review as well.

Comment: Glad someone appreciates some fun adjectives LOL :) and hope the response helped solve the larger test issue, too!